# Django DRF CSRF token missing - DRF deleted request.POST data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf-protection

I am using Django Rest's browsable API to POST using Session Authentication, and am getting CSRF token missing, even though it was supplied.  I am seeking advice on configuring my `ModelViewSet` subclass so that this works.

Here's my viewset:

```
class TreeAPI(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    queryset = Tree.objects.get_roots()
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
    throttle_classes = (TreeThrottle,)
    serializer_class = TreeSerializer
```

I am able to use the DRF Browsable API to `GET` this endpoint, but when I use it to `POST` to this endpoint, I get a 403 with the message `CSRF token missing or incorrect`.

When I set a breakpoint in [the constructor to rest_framework.request.Request](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.3.3/rest_framework/request.py#L121), I can see that the request passed in contains the needed `csrfmiddleware` token:

[image]

In Django Rest's `Request` class, `POST` is actually a property:

```
@property
def POST(self):
    if not _hasattr(self, '_data'):
        self._load_data_and_files()
    if is_form_media_type(self.content_type):
        # self.data is an empty QueryDict!
        return self.data
    return QueryDict('', encoding=self._request._encoding)
```

`request.POST` no longer contains the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` key; it is stripped of all keys supplied with the form:

[image: empty QueryDict]

As a result, the parameter passed to `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication.enforce_csrf(request)` which is then passed to `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view` does not find the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` token:

```
        if request.method == "POST":
            request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
```

What can I check? What are the possible sources of error here?

**Considerations**

- *not interested in disabling CSRF*
- *not interested in using token authentication*
- *am familiar with how to use CSRF tokens and the Django docs on them*
- *am familiar with [Django REST's docs on CSRF tokens](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/)*
- *this is the built-in Django REST browsable API; haven't modified anything in UI*

**EDIT 1 - Middleware**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

**EDIT 2 - versions of software**
 - djangorestframework==3.3.3
 - Django==1.9.8

**EDIT 3 - possibly related issues at the git project**

- ['request.data' empty when multipart form data POST in 3.3.x
  3814](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3814)
- [Request.data empty when multipart/form-data POSTed
  3951](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3951)

**EDIT 4 - possibly related stack overflow posts**
 - [Having a POST'able API and Django's CSRF Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405353/having-a-postable-api-and-djangos-csrf-middleware/14379073#14379073)
 - [How to make a POST simple JSON using Django REST Framework? CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507206/how-to-make-a-post-simple-json-using-django-rest-framework-csrf-token-missing-o?noredirect=1&lq=1)
 - [How to make a Django-Rest-Framework API that takes POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291919/how-to-make-a-django-rest-framework-api-that-takes-post-data?rq=1)
 - [Django Rest Framework, ajax POST works but PATCH throws CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813013/django-rest-framework-ajax-post-works-but-patch-throws-csrf-failed-csrf-token)
 - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser

Comment: That's strange. What's your middleware settings ? Maybe something's missing there too.

Comment: @Linovia, I don't think that's the case, since I've verified that the CSRF cookie is sent correctly. Take a look at the 2017-03-06 edit, anyway, though.

Comment: Are you able to do the request with postman or curl? Have you customized the viewset in any way? Also, why are you using all three parsers?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not manifest in `djangorestframework==3.5.4`. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/; I have a feeling this was fixed after 3.3.x.